# Use declarative Transaction in Thread created using Executor Service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a service layer class having annotation @Controller and in service call I am spawning in thread and that is updating something in database. I have used @transaction annotation in thread's method. But I am getting hibernate exception "No session found". Do I need to add any annotation to Thread?

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
>       at com.mediaiq.commons.persistence.BaseRepository.getCurrentSession(BaseRepository.java:30)
>       at com.mediaiq.cms.persistence.AgencyRepository.getById(AgencyRepository.java:20)
>       at com.mediaiq.mail.client.AgencyLookupReportByDayClient.emailAgencyLookupConfirmation(AgencyLookupReportByDayClient.java:84)
>       at com.mediaiq.mail.client.AgencyLookupReportByDayClient.sendemailreport(AgencyLookupReportByDayClient.java:67)
>       at com.mediaiq.mail.client.BaseMailClient.run(BaseMailClient.java:222)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

```
@Repository
public class BaseMailClient implements Runnable {

    public BaseMailClient() {

    }

    public BaseMailClient(PlacementsRepository placementsRepository, SessionFactory sessionFactory, String sessionID) {
    this.placementsRepository = placementsRepository;
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    this.sessionID = sessionID;
    }

    public BaseMailClient(AgencyRepository agencyRepository, SessionFactory sessionFactory, String sessionID) {

    this.agencyRepository = agencyRepository;
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    this.sessionID = sessionID;
    }

    private String      sessionID        = null;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory  sessionFactory;


    @Autowired
    private PlacementsRepository  placementsRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AgencyRepository      agencyRepository;



    final static Logger    logger          =LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseMailClient.class);



    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        sendemailreport();

    }

@Transactional
    public void sendemailreport()
    {
        checkSessionID();
        try {
        emailAgencyLookupConfirmation();
        emailAgencyLookup();
        }
        catch (IOException | FailedToCreateTempFile e) {
        logger.info("Failed To mail due to exception :" + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
        logger.info("Failed To mail due to exception :" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Service Class:

```
@Transactional
@Controller
@RequestMapping(URLEndPoints.EMAIL)
public class SendMailService {

    @Autowired
    PlacementsRepository       placementsRepository;
    @Autowired
    AgencyRepository       agencyRepository;
    /**
     * 
     */
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory   sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor mailJobExecutor;

    final static Logger     logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SendMailService.class);
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = URLEndPoints.EMAIL_AGENCY_LOOKUP_BY_DAY, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String emailAgencyLookupByDay(ServletRequest request,@PathVariable("agencyID") Integer agencyID,
              @PathVariable("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date startDate,
              @PathVariable("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date endDate )
    {
        logger.debug("POST:SendEmail:AgencyLookup");
        String sessionId = getSessionIDFromCookie(request);
        BaseClient mailServiceClient = new BaseClient(getAgencyRepository(), getSessionFactory(), sessionId);
        logger.debug("Getting Executor Instance");
        mailJobExecutor.submit(mailServiceClient);
        logger.debug("Submitted to Executor");
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you manually create a thread (or are manually using an executor service) consider the "Async" annotation. The method that runs asynchronously could call another service and the method on that service can have the "Transactional" annotation. I also think that if you are using cglib for the aspects, you could annotate the same method with both "Async" and "Transactional"

Comment: plus tell us your spring version. `@Async` and `@Transactional` had a bug before Spring-3.0.3. See [SPR-7147](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7147)

Comment: I am using 3.2 version and I have added client and service class

Comment: I don't think Spring can work defined in the way you use it. Consider using `@Async`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here.

First, you are creating your `BaseClient` object yourself, so Spring cannot add the `@Transactional` behavior.

```
BaseClient mailServiceClient = new BaseClient(getAgencyRepository(), getSessionFactory(), sessionId);
```

Instead, you should let Spring create a bean of that type for you. Use `prototype` scope.

Second, you need to carefully read this [entry in the Spring documentation about Spring's proxying mechanism.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) Unfortunately, you cannot expect any transactional behavior when invoking a `@Transactional` method from a non-transactional method within the same class, which is what you do here

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    sendemailreport();
}

@Transactional
public void sendemailreport()
{
```

`sendemailreport` is invoked on `this` reference, which is the object itself, not the proxy. It will therefore not have any transactional behavior.

[Consider looking into the `@Async` annotation alongside asynchronous execution.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support)

Comment: How can I use @Async here.. Can you please provide some example or link for example? Thanks a lot for reply!!

Comment: @Navneet The link I posted has an example and explanation.

Comment: Additional point: you can call txn method from non txn method in same class if you're using aspectj weaving (compile-time or load-time).

Answer (score 0):

Threads which are created outside Spring will not have a hibernate session attached. You will need to attach a new hibernate session to the thread manually;

```
Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.openSession(sessionFactory);
try
{
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory, new SessionHolder(session));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Logger.debug("Session already bound");
}
```

(You will need to inject the sessionFactory).

Make sure the session is unbound before the thread finishes;

```
public static void closeSession(Session se)
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(sessionFactory);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (se != null && se.isOpen() && se.isConnected())
            {
                SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(se);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        Logger.fatal("Could not close session", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _created outside Spring_? In a web application, the request handling thread is spawned from the Servlet container, not Spring's classes.

Comment: But in this case who will close the session?

Comment: Actually, to be accurate, threads are spawned by the JVM. For your question related to the term 'outside spring' would mean outside the reach of Spring's plastering capabilities.

Comment: @Navneet because this will manually provide you with an hibernate session, you will have to regulate closing the session yourself as well, i have updated the example.

Comment: `@Transactional` will work regardless of the thread. If there is no `Transaction` bound to the current thread, the proxy advisor will start one from a new `Session` created from the `TransactionManager`'s registered `SessionFactory`.

Comment: No that is not happening. I want to create A ThreadPool and submit instance of Runnable that will fetch data from database and email. To Fetch data I need transaction and session. So I tried adding @Transaction on run method of Runnable implementation. But now when I am submitting it to executor, it is giving error "No session Found". If you can provide some sample code that does same thing it will be really helpful.